# Usage de « avec » avant le nom d'une personne

Tags: sens, usage, prépositions

Quel est le sens exact du mot « avec » avant le nom d'une personne (voir par exemple les phrases ci-dessous) ? J'ai l'impression que le sens est « en suivant » ou « en imitant » ou « selon » ou « d’après » mais je ne suis pas certain.

> Avec Moeller van den Bruck, nous entendons par principe conservateur, non la défense de ce qui était hier, mais une vie fondée sur ...
>
> Avec Georges VEDEL, nous entendons par décentralisation, un mode d'organisation de l'Etat unitaire qui consiste à ...
>
> Avec O. Riemann, nous entendons par subordonnées complétives les subordonnées qui sont absolument nécessaires pour compléter ...

Comment: The inclusion of the phrase “nous entendons par” in each of these sentences confuses me because they seem redundant to me, which makes me unsure (as a non-native speaker) if my thoughts on the matter are correct, but generally I interpret “Avec + a person(X)” at the beginning of a phrase to mean : “Selon + X “ or "D'après + X" or “A entendre X.”  To avoid the redundancy that I see in these phrases, I’d change them to: ”Avec/selon/ d'après Vedel (or A entendre Vedel), la décentralisation est un mode d'organisation de l'Etat unitaire qui consiste à ... ”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le sens le plus près serait "*selon*" (ou *d'après*), mais il existe quand même une subtile nuance...

On utilise la forme "*Avec ..., nous entendons ... par ..."*, lorsqu'il s'agit de définitions qui découlent d'une branche d'études ou d'une manière de penser, propre à celle-ci, qui peut porter à confusion ou venir en conflit avec une autre définition du même mot.

Lorsqu'on dit "*d'après*", on ne fait que relever une opinion ou une parole.

Par exemple, en disant:

"D'après Richard Montigny, la population des abeilles observe une forte déclinaison"

On rapporte ce que Richard Montigny a dit, que ce soit une opinion, une mesure, etc.

Mais en disant:

"Avec Moeller van den Bruck, nous entendons par principe conservateur, non la défense de ce qui était hier, mais une vie fondée sur ..."

On informe ici qu'on utilise la définition de Moeller van den Bruck du "principe conservateur", qui sans précisions, pourrait porter à confusion lors des prochaines explications ou encore venir en conflit avec une définition générale ou sous-entendu dans le contexte.

Comment: Que pensez vous de "*Si on est du côté de*" ? En plaçant la phrase dans un contexte politique, j'ai l'impression que ça correspond bien

Comment: "être du côté de" == "donner son support à" (une personne, une idée).  C'est différent, car ici on donne notre appui (vs. être neutre, dans la question de départ)

Comment: Nice answer, especially your discussion of the nuance. It helped me greatly to resolve the redundancy issue that I was having with seeing “nous entendons par” used with the pure, non-nuanced notion of “Selon X/D’après  X” and especially “A entendre X [nous entendons par…]”  Could the nuance in “Avec X + nous entendons par…” also be captured by “Quant à X nous entendons par…” or “En ce qui concerne X nous entendons par…" ? Thanks.

Comment: "En ce qui concerne" en français signifie "pour ce qui est du sujet mentionné", donc ça ne s'utilise pas vraiment devant le nom d'une personne, à moins que son nom soit utilisé pour mentionner une situation que les 2 interlocuteurs connaissent.  "Quant à" ne s'utilise pas dans une forme "Quant à X, nous entendons...", la bonne forme serait plutôt: "Quant à X, le principe conservateur est une vie fondée...".

Answer (score 0):

le plus près serait "d'après", mais j'ai l'impression que de remplacer "Avec" par "En prenant exemple sur" nous donne une meilleure perspective!